# не работает прокрутка в ListBox из-за DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Добрый день. Обнаружил такую проблему. Есть разметка такая:

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Пол"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <DataGrid x:Name="grid2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Пол"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <DataGrid x:Name="grid3" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Пол"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ListBoxItem>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

И код с данными, если вам необходим:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<Customer> custdata = GetData();
            grid.DataContext = custdata;
            grid2.DataContext = custdata;
            grid3.DataContext = custdata;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Customer> GetData()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Customer> data = new ObservableCollection<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer{ FirstName="Дмитрий", Status="Мужской"},
                new Customer{ FirstName="Ирина", Status="Женский"},
                new Customer{ FirstName="Владимир", Status="Мужской"},
                new Customer{ FirstName="Юрий", Status="Мужской"},
                new Customer{ FirstName="Дмитрий", Status="Мужской"},
            };
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Это всё лишь для примера. ТАк вот. Когда курсор находиться на контенте в DataGrid и есть вертикальная полоса прокрутки у ListBox, то эта самая прокрутка не работает. Пытался отключить все скролы у DataGrid - не помогло. Помогло установить IsHitTestVisible="False" у DataGrid, но тогда не работает редактирование. Какое есть решение, чтобы ListBox прокручивался независимо от всех элементов? Мне прокрутка в DataGrid вообще не нужна и если вариант отключить как-то её в угоду ListBox - То это решение тоже бы подошло. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вообще здесь ListBox? Какой его функционал используется? Почему не взять обычный StackPanel?

Comment: Синтаксически более простые решения [есть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2922303/276994), но в принципе имеет смысл использовать AttachedBehavior из ответа @sp7.

Comment: Можно узнать вам подошел какой-либо из предложенных ответов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема решается следующим образом:

1) Вам не нужно вручную добавлять каждый раз элемент `ListBoxItem` в `ListBox`, для того что бы отобразить в нем элемент `DataGrid`. Для этого достаточно определить `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox>
                <DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>                  
                        <DataGridTextColumn />
                        <DataGridTextColumn />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

2) Затем нам понадобится Behavior, который будет пробрасывать событие `MouseWheel`, для того что бы работала прокрутка в `DataGrid`.

```
public class MouseWheelBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= OnPreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        var args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        args.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;

        AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(args);
    }
}
```

3) Далее добавляем созданный Behavior к DataGrid.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox>
                <DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>                  
                        <DataGridTextColumn />
                        <DataGridTextColumn />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <wpfApplication1:MouseWheelBehavior />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

4) Создаем модели, которые будем отображать в нашем списке. В простейшем виде, они могут выглядеть так:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
    }
}
```

5) Итоговая разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox Header="{Binding TableName}">
                        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Имя" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Возраст" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <wpfApplication1:MouseWheelBehavior />
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

6) Во viewModel заполняем тестовыми данными нашу коллекцию.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var item = new Item()
            {
                TableName = $"Таблица {i + 1}"
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
            {
                item.Customers.Add(new Customer()
                {
                    Name = $"Имя {j + 1}",
                    Age = j + 5
                });
            }

            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Оберните ListBox в

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" >
```

Добавьте в ListBox событие

```
PreviewMouseWheel="grid_MouseWheel"
```

Обработайте событие:

```
private void grid_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta < 0) MyScrollViewer.LineDown(); else MyScrollViewer.LineUp();
}
```

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете прогручивать не элементы внутри ListBox, а само положение ListBox'а?

Comment: Андрей. Если только имелось ввиду, использовать ListBox как контейнер для трех DataGrid, хотя рациональнее для этого в таком случае использовать StackPanel.