# Почему в WPF скроллится не тот элемент, который в фокусе, а тот, на которой наведена мышь?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть ListView, а его итемы имеют DataTemplate с тоже ListView.
В фокусе находится внешний листвью, однако когда курсор мыши находится на каком-то из внутренних - крутится внутренний, а не внешний.

То же самое если просто 2 листвью в окне.

Это не всегда удобно, как отключить хотя бы в конкретном случае (абзац 1)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705502/16781

Comment: так запретите скролл в этих элементах

Comment: @КириллМатасов рукалицо, мне не надо его там убирать совсем.

Comment: Недавно был подобный вопрос. Вот ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705460/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-listbox-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-datagrid

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто убрать прокрутку в этих элементах.

Конечно оно будет работать так! Если поместить в один `ScrollViewer` другой, то прокрутка будет выполняться в первую очередь в последнем (во дочернем).